# Is a high Collision Count in WAN an issue?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a NETGEAR CG3000v2 modem/router. I found a stats page which has:

```
System Up Time      938:32:16
Port    Status      TxPkts      RxPkts      Collisions      Tx B/s      Rx B/s      Up Time
WAN     Link Up     35517385    536710913   1084322615      3139295536  3883053408  938:32:16
LAN1    Link Down   94858931    67613264    5               2584963697  2594258290  938:32:16
LAN2    Link Down                                                                   938:32:16
LAN3    1Gbps/Full                                                                  938:32:16
LAN4    1Gbps/Full                                                                  938:32:16
WLAN    450M        68906       3113237     0               1597122208  586011635   938:32:16
```

Is the collisions column important? It seems very high for WAN - should this concern me?

Comment: Relevant: [Collision errors reported by Cisco router interface](http://serverfault.com/q/565255)

Comment: [Ethernet Collisions and Troubleshooting](http://ipcisco.com/ethernet-collisions-and-troubleshooting/)

Comment: Both these seem to suggest a common cause is Duplexing - given I don't even know what that is I doubt I've set that to happen.

Comment: As the errors are on the WAN side you should speak to your ISP. There may be a misconguration at their end.

Comment: Assuming this is a *cable*modem, then it is not unusual as cable is a shared medium.  You and many of your neighbors are using the same copper wire to transmit, so at any given time, only one can do so.  Sometimes two try, and you get a collision.